# how to make wait into a fetch call in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to make a breack of 1 sec into a fetch call and it doesn't work,
the code is this:

```
async function sendStats(image, endimage, chat, id) {
   let finalimage = image + endimage;
     fetch(finalimage)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
            res.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./imgs/image.png'));
            bot.sendPhoto(chat, finalimage);
        } else {
            finalimage = image + "i" + endimage;
            fetch(finalimage)
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.ok) {
                        res.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./imgs/image.png'));
                        bot.sendPhoto(chat, finalimage);
                    } else {
                        bot.sendMessage(chat, "spiacenti ma non abbiamo un immagine di questo mostro :(");
                    }
                })

        }
        let mstr = mostri.filter(x => x.id == id);
        let desc = mstr[0].description;
        let elements = mstr[0].elements;
        await sleep(1000);
        bot.sendMessage(chat, desc);

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}

function sleep(ms) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});
}
```

i want to send the bot.sendmessage of desc after the sendphoto because is reversed now, and it doesn't give me message errors

Comment: And what error message do you get? (The shown code would not run at all but result in a syntax error)

Comment: You can only use `await` withint an `async` function which you don't have here. Use `.then(async (res) => { await sleep(1000); })`.

Comment: `and it doesn't give me message errors` this claim you added is wrong if the code you show is the actual code. The shown code will not run and will result in an error message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are using the `await` keyword without an `async` function.

---

I think you might've gotten confused with this `async` function when using the `await` keyword with `sleep()`.

```js
async function sendStats(image, endimage, chat, id) {}
```

The issue is that your `sleep()` function is inside another function, so the `sendStats()` function won't help with its `await` keyword.

---

The solution for this issue is to add an `async` keyword to the function that the `sleep()` function is in.

```js
fetch(finalImage)
  .then(async (res) => {
    await sleep(1000);
  });
```

<sub>**Line 2** has been modified.</sub>

The reason this works is because the function in which the `await` keyword is in has the `async` keyword added onto the function, which specifies that the function has an asynchronous task in it.

---

In conclusion, the issue with your code was that you had forgotten to add the `async` keyword to the function which had `await` in there.